# Pandas combine df with a list by duplicating records for each list element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this.

```
Date
2022-10-22
2022-10-21
2022-10-20
```

I want to combine and duplicate for each element in this list
`['NAB', 'CBA']`

To get a result df like this.

```
Date        Bank
2022-10-22  NAB
2022-10-22  CBA
2022-10-21  NAB
2022-10-21  CBA
2022-10-20  NAB
2022-10-20  CBA
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
lst = ['NAB', 'CBA']
out = df.merge(pd.Series(lst, name='Bank'), how='cross')
```

Output:

```
         Date Bank
0  2022-10-22  NAB
1  2022-10-22  CBA
2  2022-10-21  NAB
3  2022-10-21  CBA
4  2022-10-20  NAB
5  2022-10-20  CBA
```

Answer (score 1):

Add fixed Bank=["NAB", "CBA"] column to df:

```py
df["Bank"] = df.apply(lambda _: ["NAB", "CBA"], axis=1)

[Out]:
        date        Bank
0 2022-10-22  [NAB, CBA]
1 2022-10-21  [NAB, CBA]
2 2022-10-20  [NAB, CBA]
```

Then explode date column:

```py
df = df.explode("Bank")

[Out]:
        date Bank
0 2022-10-22  NAB
0 2022-10-22  CBA
1 2022-10-21  NAB
1 2022-10-21  CBA
2 2022-10-20  NAB
2 2022-10-20  CBA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
lst = [['NAB', 'CBA']]

df['Bank'] = lst * len(df)
df.explode('Bank')
```

Output:

```
         Date Bank
0  2022-10-22  NAB
0  2022-10-22  CBA
1  2022-10-21  NAB
1  2022-10-21  CBA
2  2022-10-20  NAB
2  2022-10-20  CBA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1= ['NAB','CBA']
df1.assign(col1=var1.__str__())\
    .assign(col1=lambda x:x.col1.map(eval))\
    .explode('col1')
```

[image]